# What's wrong with that django app?

Tags: django, tastypie

I am following that tutorial http://thecodachi.blogspot.com/2012/03/django-tastypie-with-android-client.html  and https://github.com/Mbosco/tastypie-api-example
I did all things in the tutorial but,  I am getting an error "No module named recipe_resource.urls", When I run "localhost:8000/api/recipes/?format=json"
Could you please help me how to fix it ?

Comment: You don't have a file called `recipe_resource.py`, do you?

Comment: Nope, it is called queryset = Recipe.objects.all() and that refers Recipe

Comment: That's not what he was asking. Do you literally have a file named "recipe_resource.py"?

Comment: Try to change this `url(r'^api/', include('recipe_resource.urls')),` with this: `url(r'^api/', include(recipe_resource.urls)),` (without the simple quotes)

Comment: Thanks, it works. One more question, if I post recipes(name and content) from android using http post, What should I use as a method to records the sent data from android to database of django ?

Comment: so that, I should be able to run that command which is "curl -i -X PUT -H Accept:application/json -H Content-Type:application/json  -d '{id:47,recipe:{name:"Salad",content:"Lettuce"}}' 'http://localhost/api/recipes'      "

Comment: Oh! It's great to know it worked! I will add it as answer in order to get your question answered and people don't get confused... I didn't understand your last question, but i think the best is that you add that as a new question because it is a different issue... If you want, add a link to that question here to see if we can continue helping you....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change this

```
url(r'^api/', include('recipe_resource.urls')),
```

with this:

```
url(r'^api/', include(recipe_resource.urls)), #without the simple quotes in the "include" parameter
```

Answer (score 1):

In my implementation of tastypie, I have something similar to the following:

```
from tastypie.api import Api
from recipes.api import RecipeResource

v1_api = Api(api_name='v1')
v1_api.register(RecipeResource())

urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^api/', include(v1_api.urls)),
)
```

Perhaps, try that. Even if it doesn't improve the situation, you'll want to do it that way, anyways, because otherwise you couldn't add more than one resource.

Comment: I have tried and I got that error "name 'urlpatterns' is not defined"

Comment: Ok. First off, that needs to go in your main urls.py file, not your app's, and second, it needs to come after the first time you define `urlpatterns`. If it *is* the first time, then just remove the `+`.

Comment: I guess it works, even though I got this time "Page not found (404)" error, Right ?

Comment: And in this case, How can I access admin page ?

Comment: Huh? The first time you use `urlpatterns` use `=`, every other time use `+=`.

Comment: I mean, localhost/admin/ also gives the same error which is "Page not found (404)", How can I access the admin page ? Also, When i change = to +=, it does not work ....

Comment: Wow. OK. Once more from the top: `urlpatterns` only exists within the context of the particular urls.py file, and then it only exists after you initially store something to it `=`. If you try to use `+=` before you use `=` once already, you'll get an error. After you've used `=` the *first time* every subsequent time you add something to `urlpatterns` you need to use `+=` or else you will overwrite anything else that's been previously stored in it. This is simple Python 101.